# Bound mismatch: type is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter

Tags: java, generics

I am getting the following error `Bound mismatch: The type FFTWTask is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends AbsTask<T>> of the type AbsStage<T,U>`

I am representing an abstract stage:

```
public abstract class AbsStage<T extends AbsTask<T>, U extends AbsTask<U>> { }
```

Where an AbsTask is:

```
public abstract class AbsTask <T> { }
```

Then I create an AbsTask called FFTWTask:

```
public class FFTWTask extends AbsTask<Double>{ }
```

Finally, I create an AbsStage called FFTWStage:

```
public class FFTWStage extends AbsStage<FFTWTask, FFTWTask>{ } // Error occurs here
```

What am I missing with my understanding of generics. I have found numerous posts that feature the same error message, but I cant seem to decipher them.

Here is a simple class that achieves the error:

```
public class Test {
  public abstract class AbsTask <T> { }
  public class FFTWTask extends AbsTask<Double>{ }

  public abstract class AbsStage<T extends AbsTask<T>, U extends AbsTask<U>> { }
  public class FFTWStage extends AbsStage<FFTWTask, FFTWTask>{ } // Error here <-
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the type parameter `T` in `AbsStage` must extend `AbsTask<T>`, then `FFTWTask` must extend `AbsTask<FFTWTask>` in order to be used in `FFTWStage`:

```
public class FFTWTask extends AbsTask<FFTWTask>{ }
```

Comment: This resolves the error in the test. Now how to represent some data type for a task so that I can have a task hold a Double (or some other type) in it.

Comment: You could remove the recursive type boundary from `T` and `U` in `AbsStage` (`AbsStage<T extends AbsTask, U extends AbsTask>`)

Comment: Yup that resolved the issue. Thank yo uso much. Seriously generics give me huge headaches sometimes... And thanks for helping me step through it

Comment: Just a question: would it be possible to have AbsStage to expect T and U to be of some type AbsTask: for instance does this make sense : public abstract class AbsStage<T extends AbsTask<?>, U extends AbsTask<?>> { }